# asp.net website design trouble

Tags: asp.net, templates, web

Hi I am developing a website with multiple pages. I am a beginner, coding is still a challenge for me, but my main hardship is designing my website. Visual studio is very not intuitive when it comes to designing websites, and sometimes you feel (when you try to design) like you work while tied in a straightjacket. I am used to dragging stuff around when designing, but this doesn't work with websites. There are a lot of website templates, but is there any which work with asp.net? And how do you integrate them while working in visual studio? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any special templates to work with ASP.Net. Integrating a template works the exact same way as it would if you are designing a site from scratch.

Find out your major pieces that are in every page (or groups of pages) and create your master pages that will provide consistent layout for those pages.

Forget about dragging and dropping and pixel design locations of a regular desktop app, it's not going to work that way.

Start with a framework such as Bootstrap, or a template based on Bootstrap. It's extremely well documented, works cross-platform, and there are plenty of tutorials out there on using it.

Visual Studio works pretty much like any other web design tool does. You're just running into exactly how things have been done for well over a decade now. Tools get better, but the web is an entirely different experience that requires entirely different ways of doing things.

You can easily templates or frameworks into your site. You can add styling to form fields, buttons, etc. easily through the CSS of the template.

Take a look at [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) to get an idea of how you can style elements and understand the layout tricks that can be accomplished with responsive design.